# Custom Input Styling

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm wanting to make an input field like image 1 but currently am stuck with image 2's grey border... I have tried using outline: none, outline-width: 0 everything and I still can't get rid of the outline to do something like image 1...  All help would be much appreciated!

Img 1
[image]

Img 2
[image]

Comment: Please post your code ...

Comment: Can you post your code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `border: none` and `border-color: transparent`

Sample

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here">
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the border simply use the CSS property **border**:

```
border: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  background-color: transparent;
  color:#000;
}
input:focus {

  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border:none
```

this might do the trick !